# Create Trigger which updates a column automatically after update of a table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have a table which looks like this:

|idAvailability|SumRooms|AvailableRooms|AvailabilityRate|

everything is int except AvailabilityRate which is float.
I want to create a trigger which when updating the AvailableRooms column, automatically because of the existance of the trigger the column AvailabilityRate update as well.

This is what I have done so far.

```
CREATE TRIGGER availability_BEFORE_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON availability
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update availability
    set new.AvailabilityRate = new.AvailableRooms/new.SumRooms;
END
```

But it throws me this error:

Executing:
`UPDATE ergasia.availability SET AvailableRooms=15 WHERE idAvailability=1;`

ERROR 1442: 1442: `Can't update table availability in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
SQL Statement:
UPDATE ergasia.availability SET AvailableRooms=15 WHERE idAvailability=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not update the same table where the trigger is getting executed. Since you are using `before update` all you need to set the `new` value of `AvailabilityRate`

So the trigger becomes

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER availability_BEFORE_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON availability 
FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN 
  set new.AvailabilityRate=new.AvailableRooms/new.SumRooms;
 END;//
delimiter;
```

Comment: 20:06:36 CREATE TRIGGER availability_BEFORE_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON availability  FOR EACH ROW   BEGIN    set new.AvailabilityRate=new.AvailableRooms/new.SumRooms;  END; Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' 
This is what it displays when I am trying to create it. I user MySQL WorkBench
0.000 sec

Comment: You have some other trigger for this table with `before update` hence you are getting this error. You need to reconcile everything in one trigger and by removing others.

Comment: Well, yeah you were right! I forgot to remove the old trigger! So, thanks again! @Abhik Chakraborty

Answer (score 0):

You should only need this part:

`SET NEW.AvailabilityRate := NEW.AvailableRooms/NEW.SumRooms;`

You are not updating a row, you are modifying the values a row is being updated with.